# Qt Can't download file using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, http, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

In my project, I need to download a simple .txt file. I created a function to download the file based on the url:

```
void MainWindow::downloadFile(const QString &url, const QString &aPathInClient)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager* m_NetworkMngr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_NetworkMngr->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
    QUrl aUrl(url);
    QFileInfo fileInfo=aUrl.path();

    QFile file(aPathInClient+"\\"+fileInfo.fileName());
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    file.write(reply->readAll());
    delete reply;
}
```

When my program is ran, the file is created with the correct file name, but the file is empty. The file name can only be obtained by my program if is connect to the webpage. What am I forgetting? I get no errors on build and have included all the necessary libraries.

Thanks :)

EDIT:

All is well, my problem was my link used https instead of http.

Comment: Try to write a known string literal instead of reply->readAll()

Comment: I have never used string literals. Is it possible to get a quick example?

Comment: First check there's actually data downloaded: Check what readAll() returns (store it in a QByteArray and use a debugger or print it using toHex()) and check reply->errorString().

Answer (score 1):

I haven't ever used the 'write' function for writing to a `QFile`. Try the following approach:

```
QFile file(aPathInClient+"\\"+fileInfo.fileName());
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QTextStream out(&file);
out << "This file is generated by Qt\n";
```

EDIT: The above was just to check whether the file is being written to correctly or not. Now since it has been verified, you can try:

```
out << reply->readAll();
```

Comment: Im testing it now, but im curious as to how it knows to get the file from reply?

Comment: All that was written was "This file is generated by Qt"

Comment: That assumes that the data downloaded is text. I'd first `qDebug() << reply->errorString() << reply->readAll().toHex()`.

Comment: I have edited my op. I found my problem and it was simply because I was trying to access a secured url. I apologize :/

Comment: @mc360pro well you could write a full answer to your own question explaining the correction if greater details.